# How to remove a product from WooCoomerce

Tags: woocommerce

On our site we are using WooCommerce and the Subscription extension and this is working fine.  However, we have recently decided that we are going to remove our subscription service.  But what I am concerned about is how to properly remove the subscription setup.

I have manually gone thru and cancelled any active subscriptions so they will no longer be billed.  And on a future date (to make sure people have access till the end of their current billing cycle) we plan to completely remove subscriptions.

Would removing the subscriptions extension plugin cause problems?   What would be the best method of removing the subscription products (currently I have set the subscription item to out of stock and also set it to private so no more orders can be placed).  If I delete the subscription product completely would that affect the sales reports (I am guessing it would as the product would no longer exists).

Also how would deleting a product affect orders where that product was purchased?  Would the order just simply show no items (but keep the totals)?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I would delete every subscription product, just go to your woocommerce products and filter by the category you set your subscriptions too and delete them all.

Then on the day which your last sub expires remove the plugin in the normal method.

Comment: Thanks Chris - that would be the preferred method.  Do you think that this would screw up the reports (as the products no longer exist)?  I am also worried about previous orders and what they would show for items purchased.

Comment: No, the order history in woocommerce should not be affected, the history will remain intact regardless of the items existence. when you look at the order details it will still show the products, however, if you try to click them you'll get an *item does not exist* message. As long as the subscription is not directly accessed through the products existance you will be fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you have them as out of stock and private/hidden, that should be good enough until all the subs are finished. I wouldn't remove them as products until at least the last orders are created. If you do, they may not generate.